# Is it possible to run a visual studio solution automatically at random times of the day?

Tags: visual-studio, scheduled-tasks

I have created a solution in visual studio, which is basically code to test the functionality of a website using an automated web driver. I would like to know  the simplest way to run this solution periodically based on a set interval time, like at 2 am everyday or every 24 hours. For example, if some one knew how to use a scheduling system, script, or anything like these that could **RUN** the solution automatically, please contribute your knowledge. This information is mainly for newbies to Visual Studio like myself. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that to do this involves two things.

1. After writing your unit test, write a batch file that contains the MSTest.exe command to run the tests that you want. The batch file should change to the directory, rebuild the solution, and run your unit test.
2. Use the windows scheduler to schedule regular time intervals for executing the batch file.

More specific information on how to do this is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243181(v=vs.100).aspx).

Thanks for your kind attention.

Answer (score 1):

If/when Visual Studio can support running multiple instances during development, you can use the built-in Windows 7 Task Scheduler (Start -> All Programs -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler).

There are multiple tutorials available on the internet to assist you with setting up a recurring task in the Task Scheduler. Here is one example:

http://www.ampercent.com/using-windows-7-task-scheduler-to-run-any-installed-program/7744/

Comment: Please do not post spam answers on the site?

Comment: This is pretty blatant plagiarism with no credit given to the source as well as not really answering the question. [Here is one example of a page using this exact text](http://www.ampercent.com/using-windows-7-task-scheduler-to-run-any-installed-program/7744/).

Comment: Source : http://www.ampercent.com/using-windows-7-task-scheduler-to-run-any-installed-program/7744/

Comment: @WemboMulumba You directly plagiarized an answer that didn't even apply to the question. Even after you have now have edited your answer, it still is not relevant as it is not useful. I am trying to run a visual studio solution automatically, which is cannot be done by simply using a task scheduler. Please revisit my question or remove your answer.